# How to switch between Google Chrome beta and stable on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I'm currently having an issue with chrome beta (i. e., [this problem](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=146466)).

**How can I switch to Google Chrome stable? How would I go back if I want the beta again?**

Comment: Did you install Chrome using ppa?

Answer (score 3):

It was actually simpler than I thought it would be.

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager
2. Quick filter: "chrome"
3. `google-chrome-beta`: "Mark for removal"
4. `google-chrome-stable`: "Mark for installation"
5. Press "Apply".

If you want to go back to the beta channel, do the reverse in steps 3 and 4.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 16 and I can install both beta and stable version of Chrome. Of course, to run them, use the command as you stated `google-chrome-beta` and `google-chorme-stable` or just `google-chrome`